# Error while using Single Sign-On with OpenSSO

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to use salesforce federated single signon feature. I am using Glassfish server and OpenSSO 8.0

While logging in using OpenSSO, I am getting the following error:

> Login Error  Your login attempt using single sign-on with an identity
>   provider certificate has failed. Please contact your salesforce.com
>   administrator for more information.

Can anyone suggest any solution regarding this ?

Comment: Hi can you guide me in configuring Open SSO ,i am struggling with it .I have Installed Glassfish server.All I need now is to config Open SSO

Answer (score 7):

In the org, go to **Setup | Security Controls | Single Sign-On Settings** and click the **SAML Assertion Validator** button. If the SSO attempt got as far as your org, you should see something there that will lead you towards identifying the problem.

If there is nothing listed in the SAML Assertion Validator, then Salesforce is not able to identify the correct org from the assertion. Go into the OpenSSO logs, copy the SAML assertion, and paste it into the SAML Assertion Validator. Again, this should lead you towards resolution.

Comment: Thanks metadaddy, I was able to find the cause of the error. I had provided Universal ID of different subject of Open SSO in salesforce user's Federation ID field and was trying to login from a different subject's credentials. That's why it was giving error. Once I tried to login from the same subject, it worked fine. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: How do i get to the OpenSSO logs?

Comment: @nivyaj http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19681-01/820-3885/gjqdm/index.html