# SSO with ADFS 2.0

Tags: single-sign-on

I am setting up SSO with ADFS 2.0.  Have followed these instructions:
http://blog.rhysgoodwin.com/cloud/salesforce-sso-with-adfs-2-0-everything-you-need-to-know/

And everything was working fine until two days ago.  Suddenly it stopped working and getting an error.  Thought it was a certificate problem so we got a real certificate (instead of self-signed).  After updating the info in SFDC SSO panel, I now get nothing in the SAML Validation screen.  I read this post: [Error while using Single Sign-On with OpenSSO](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/error-while-using-single-sign-on-with-opensso) 
So I'm stuck looking for the SAML assertion to paste into the validator.  However, I have no idea where to find this.  The processing is still going through my in house server, and I thought of looking through the ADFS logs in Event Viewer but no luck so far.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: By certificate, are you referring to the token sigining cert that you import in the SSO settings screen on Salesforce? If you have selected Federation id, check that the Federation Id on the User is set correctly - the federation id is case sensitive in my experience.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing in the SAML Validation screen" - like uploading an assertion has no effect? Or that it appears to be valid? A screenshot may help. Also, post the actual error to clarify what you mean by "stopped working and getting an error".

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Yes, I am referring to the token signing cert.  I have tried all of the different options as far as Federation ID and User ID go, and changed the binding in ADFS as well.

Comment: jkraybill- I cannot figure out where to FIND the assertion to upload.  Do you have any ideas where that would be stored?  Th rror I'm getting is:  "Login Error Your login attempt using single sign-on with an identity provider certificate has failed. Please contact your salesforce.com administrator for more information."

Comment: @jkraybill  I tried to attach a screen shot of the settings but it says I need to have  10 reputation first.

Comment: You find the assertion in the blank screen you VERY briefly see after logging into your identity provider but before you see a Salesforce error. You hit "esc" in your browser to freeze the page before it posts, and then view source and find a base64-encoded assertion. Decode it and then paste it into the validator.

Comment: @bendparker, did you get this resolved? If so, could you share with us what the resolution was for the benefit of others or let us know who's comments provided the answer you needed?